# Return a combo box based on another combo box selection

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have a SharePoint list labeled GL_Loc_Dept that has two columns labeled 'GL - GL Descr' and 'Loc - Loc Descr'. Both columns are of data type choices.

In Power Apps, I have a combo box for each column labeled GLComboBox and LocComboBox resepectively. The user should be able to select any 'GL - GL Descr' from the GLComboBox and when they click on LocComboBox, the combo box should only display the records from that GL. In essence, it needs to filter.

This is what I currently have

```
--GLComboBox Items
Items = Choices(GL_Loc_Dept.'GL - GL Descr')

--LocComboBox Items
Items = 
Filter(
    Choices(GL_Loc_Dept.'Loc - Loc Descr'),
    Value in Filter(GL_Loc_Dept, 'GL - GL Descr'.Value = GLComboBox.Selected.Value).Title
    )
```

When I make a GL selection, the app does seem to act like it's refreshing but then the loc doesn't display anything.

Comment: Is 'Loc - Loc Descr' column of type single selection or multiple selection choice column?